"Не дорос". Почему раздельно?
Почему в данном слове глагол пишется с частицей раздельно и не подпадает под правило приставка недо с глаголами?
Можем подобрать слово, имеющее противоположное значение превышения нормы - "Перерос".
По значению само слово можно определить под несоответствие норме, какому-то уровню, разве нет?

«...Не подпадает под правило приставка недо с глаголами слитно». А  если перевести на руссский?


По правилу Розенталя следует отличать приставку НЕДО со значением недостаточности действия/состояния  от сочетания НЕ + ДО со значением не довести действие/состояние до конца или до определенного предела.

Важно отметить следующее: между двумя вариантами должна быть качественная разница. Сравним, к примеру, варианты не досмотреть (до конца) и недосмотреть (плохо смотреть): И как недосмотрел! И как недослышал! Впрочем, фильм он так и не досмотрел: уснул.

По словарю существуют глаголы дорасти и перерасти, но глагола недорасти в словаре нет. Это можно объяснить тем,  что нет качественной разницы между двумя вариантами дорасти и до расти, то есть разница только количественная.


Например:  Он не мастер спорта, не дорос еще (предел роста обозначен). Его не берут пока в основной состав, не дорос.   Кажется, что разница есть, но по сути это именно количественная разница в мастерстве.
В Карте слов также обозначена только форма не дорасти.

Качественную разницу можно увидеть в существительном недоросль:
НЕДОРОСЛЬ, -я; м. 1. В России до конца 18 века: дворянин, 
не достигший совершеннолетия и не поступивший ещё на 
государственную службу. 2. Недоучившийся, глуповатый 
молодой человек. Не будешь учиться, останешься недорослем 
до старости лет. По названию комедии Д.И. Фонвизина 
"Недоросль."


В литературе иногда встречаются единичные написания недорос, если автор видит качественное значение недостаточности:


Н. Садур. Ехай (1984)  Ты руки-то больно не распускай! Недорос еще!
Андрей Белый. На рубеже двух столетий (1929)
В одном отношении я перерос своих сверстников; ну а в другом — недорос: Коля, Саша, Маруся уже твердо знали, с кого что сорвать и кого как использовать из «знаменитостей» для нужд их детской: утилитаристы!
Г. П. Данилевский. Воля (1863)
Говорит об англомании! куда тебе до лордов! Недорос!
ПРАВИЛО
§ 59. Частица не с глаголами
Пункт 5. Следует различать глаголы с приставкой НЕДО- (придает глаголу значение неполноты, недостаточности действия и по значению часто антонимична приставке ПЕРЕ-):
недоедать, недосыпать, недосмотреть, недослышать, 
недоучесть, недобрать баллов, недоварить картофель; 
недовернуть гайку, недовесить масла; недовыполнить план; 
недоглядеть за ребёнком; недогрузить вагон; недооценить свои 
возможности; недополучить часть товара 

и созвучные им глаголы с приставкой ДО-, которой предшествует отрицание НЕ (в сочетании с частицей глагол обозначает, что действие не доведено до конца):
 не досмотреть спектакль **до конца** (‘не окончить 
 смотреть’); дети часто не доедали суп; никогда не 
 доплачивали.


ИЗ ПРИНЯТОГО В ЭТОЙ ТЕМЕ ОТВЕТА:

По словарю существуют глаголы дорасти и перерасти, но глагола недорасти в словаре нет.

На самом деле современными словарями глагол НЕДОРАСТИ фиксируется.
См.:

Современный толковый словарь русского языка Ефремовой:

недорасти́
см. недорастать
недораста́ть
Не достигать полного или нормального роста.


Большой универсальный словарь русского языка Морковкина и др.:

недо|расти сов. → недораст|а(ть) несов. (к знач. 1.0., 2.0., 2.0.1., 3.0.)


Словообразовательный словарь русского языка Тихонова в 2 т.:




Встречается этот глагол и в школьных учебниках.
См.:





"Не" с глаголом раздельно пишут при незавершённости действия (процесс можно возобновить и довести до конца). "Недо" слитно пишут, чтобы показать недостаточность действия.
Соответственно, акцент "не дорос" на том, что ещё может дорасти, а не на том, что рос недостаточно интенсивно.

Второй ответ
В ПЕРВОМ ОТВЕТЕ НАЗВАНА ВОЗМОЖНАЯ ПРИЧИНА ТОГО, ПОЧЕМУ ГЛАГОЛА "НЕДОРАСТИ" НЕТ В ОРОГРАФИЧЕСКОМ СЛОВАРЕ РАН, А ТАКЖЕ ПОЧЕМУ ЭТО СЛОВО НЕ ИСПОЛЬЗУЕТСЯ В ПРАКТИКЕ ПИСЬМА.
Поэтому предлагаю отвечающим всё же раскрыть основную тему вопроса: ТАК ПОЧЕМУ ЖЕ? Работа с источниками важна на форуме, но не менее важен лингвистический анализ этих источников.
ОСНОВНАЯ ЧАСТЬ

Орфографию слова недорасти следует проверять по словарю РАН, но там нет этого глагола.

Нормы орографии могут меняться, толковые, словообразовательные и все прочие словари разных лет, а также школьные учебники — это не лучший способ узнать нормы  письма на текущий момент.
Орфографический академический ресурс «Академос» — постоянно обновляемый официальный онлайн-словарь Института русского языка РАН. Последнее на текущий момент обновление состоялось в декабре 2023 года.

№ 204517
Здравствуйте, уважаемая Грамота.Ру! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно: "Вундеркиндам не интересно со сверстниками, а до взрослых они еще "недоросли" ( " не доросли"? Спасибо.
ОТВЕТ.
Корректно раздельное написание.

Карта слов:  Предложения со словосочетанием «не дорасти»


Там нет глагола дорасти. Поэтому предлагаю отвечающим привести ПРИМЕРЫ ИЗ ЛИТЕРАТУРЫ.
Один из многих примеров: Как правило, духовность, понимаемая в таком смысле, оперирует социальными проблемами на таком уровне рефлексии, до которого основная масса человечества ещё не доросла. Андрей Флиер, Культурология для культурологов. Учебное пособие для магистрантов, аспирантов и соискателей, 2015

НКРЯ: недорос — только несколько единичных примеров преимущественно из старых текстов.

Особое внимание этому примеру с парным написанием: Андрей Белый. На рубеже двух столетий (1929). В одном отношении я перерос своих сверстников; ну а в другом — недорос...

Почему всё же нет в словаре РАН слова недорасти? Практически всегда имеется в виду ориентир, который еще на достигнут: возраст, духовное, физическое или социальное развитие. Этот конкретный (количественный) ориентир присутствует во всех темах.

Для сравнения: Русский орфографический словарь;
недосмотреть, -отрю, -отрит (наблюдая, не заметить всего, не уберечь), но: не досмотреть (так и не досмотрел фильм).  Вот здесь качество обозначено: не заметить, не уберечь.

И еще раз повторяю основную мысль своего ответа: орографический словарь РАН закрепляет те написания слов, которые актуальны на текущий момент, а современная практика показывает практически полное отсутствие глагол недорасти в текстах. В то же время частные варианты с такой орфографией возможны (при наличии противопоставления:   недорасти — перерасти).

ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Вообще говоря, тема парных вариантов для приставки НЕДО  довольно сложна: у пользователей часто возникают сомнения и принимаются ошибочные решения.  Поэтому не стоит из-за нескольких частных случаев нормировать парное написание этого глагола.
P. S. А это примеры такого сомнительного выбора для пары недосмотреть — не досмотреть:
 Обошли его, и он чего-то не досмотрел.
 Побывал в мастерской: кабы не досмотрел, проквасили шерсть.
 Не достает только, чтобы в газетах напечатали.
 А что не достает ста пятидесяти рублей, это только 
 частность.
 При такой погоде не достает смелости идти под парусами.

Так что понятным становится решение словаря РАН относительно парного варианта для не дорасти.

Sharon: «Орфографию слова НЕДОРАСТИ следует проверять по словарю РАН, но там нет этого глагола» === Всё так. Но в этом словаре нет, к примеру, и глагола НЕДОГРЕТЬ. Из факта отсутствия этого слова в РОС не следует же вывод, что его нет сегодня в русском языке?

Ни в Карте слов, ни в НКРЯ примеров для «недогреть» тоже нет. Вероятно, слово бытовое, нет необходимости такие слова нормировать.
В принципе для каждого слова с ПЕРЕ можно подобрать слово с НЕДО, но не все они используются в письменной речи. Кстати, ваша собственная версия какая? Почему одни есть, а других нет? Или задайте вопрос специалистам из РАН.
